# Override groupprincipal.members.add

Tags: c#, directoryservices, account-management

Anyone knows if it is possible to override or extend the Members.Add method on a `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal` object?

I would like to do something like this

```
public new void Add(Principal principal)
{
    base.Add(principal);
    LogFile.WriteLine("Added {0} to group", principal.Name);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, as you aren't trying to override a method on `GroupPrincipal`, but on a child object inside of `GroupPrincipal`, namely the `PrincipalCollection` object that represents the Members.

The only way to kind of do what you want is to put the Add method as just an ordinary method on your child object, something like:

```
public class EnhancedGroupPrincipal : Group Principal {    
    public void Add(Principal principal) {
        //your code to add and log
    }    
}
```

While you would have to know to use the alternate `Add` method, presumably you would know, so it would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I can figure out is using an extension method

```
public static void Add(this GroupPrincipal group, Principal child)
{
     group.Members.Add(child);
     LogFile.WriteLine("Added {0} to group", child.Name);
     //Do whatever else you have to do...
}
```